# Big reading function in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have a big reading function and it slows the app a bit down. So I heard something of AsyncTasks. How can I put this function into an AsyncTask, the best would be in an external class, e.g. `Reading.java` and call this function every time I need from the MainActivity.java

Can anyone help me?

Edit: Important is that I need to give the function a String as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a AsyncTask that takes a String parameter like this:

```
public class LargeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground(String... strings) {
         String your_string = strings[0]; //Retrieve the first parameter
         //Your "big reading function" goes here
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         //Do something when done
     }
 }
```

Then you can call and run it like this:

```
new LargeTask().execute(your_string_parameter);
```

More info on the AsyncTask can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).